# Songs similar to Runescape game remix "Har'Money"

Tags: remix, techno

There's a remix song based on a game called Runescape that I really like and want to make a playlist of other songs that are like it too but I can't find anything similar.

The song can be heard here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqiN7QfSr-c

I tried searching for dubstep or techno but none of those sound right. I really like the upbeat nature of this song along with it's use of non-instruments (although having instruments are fine too). Above all anything similar shouldn't have words. Part of why I like this is it's just a plain fun song.

Are there any suggestions on specific songs similar or maybe a better clarification on what genre I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The remix is done in the style that was popular in the 90s called **big beat**.

It was basically breakbeat with very straightforward grooves sampled.  The samples were stacked in a fashion to create a noisy but robust sound that invited the dancers to do torsion dances that were familiar from rock n roll.  Big names in this genre were Fat Boy Slim and Chemical Brothers.

[Here is a mixtape that dwells on this moment.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVysHOfV8CI)